# set right to left radio button in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `Farsi` language which is a `right to left`.
I have couples of problems with this feature in `Bootstrap (version 3.3.6)`.
For example in radio button I want that the radio put in the right of the associated label.

```
<div class="row container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form role="form">
    <h4><font face="B Nazanin">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
        گزینه اول
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
        گزینه دوم
    </label>
   </font></h4>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried many option like direction:"rtl", text-align, text-right, pull-right, etc. but they did not work.
Also, I want to put whole of the form at the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply broke your Markup, place your `label`s before the `input`s and the radio `input`s will naturally appear on the right side of their associated `label`.

Your Markup will look like this:

```
<div class="row container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form role="form">
    <h4><font face="B Nazanin">
    <label for="id1" class="radio-inline">
    گزینه دوم   
    </label> 
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="id1"> 
    <label for="id2" class="radio-inline">
    گزینه اول     
    </label> 
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="id2"> 
   </font></h4>
  </form>
</div>
```

And here's the [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/JPqyMwjwzh).

**EDIT:**

You mentioned in your last line that youd'd like the whole thing to be centered.

There's three options for that:

[Center your content by only using  `.container`](http://www.bootply.com/7gZZBbqrMo)

[Center your text with `text-align:center;`](http://www.bootply.com/NQWR14M9vJ)

[Center your content by using Bootstrap's grid system](http://www.bootply.com/8x36KHGd6q)

Comment: your solution is correct, however there is a problem:
when you click on a label, its radio did not choose

Comment: Check it again, i just added that, when using labels you should use `for`, indicating which radio the label belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

So if your language is Persian just like me, i assume that your body would be in right-to-left direction, [**this is the Working Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/iB95m5vLg3).
Btw there is a library for RTL version of bootstrap that i think will suit for u, take a look at [this library](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl).

Comment: But when the direction of body change to rtl, radio and label overlapped with each other and label put almost under the radio!!!

Comment: Yes it will, because bootstrap default direction is LTR and u need to change directions of all of the elements to RTL too.

Comment: I set direction of all elements to rtl however it still overlapped

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add a bit of your own css styles

first change markup to this -

```
<div class="row container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form role="form">
   <h4><font face="B Nazanin">
    <label class="radio-inline">
     گزینه اول
     <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
     گزینه دوم
     <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    </label>
  </font></h4>
 </form>
</div>
```

then add to you css file these styles -

```
.radio-inline {
      display: inline;
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 20px;
}
.radio-inline input {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: This sadly breaks the code, the inputs overlap the labels. Also there is no need for custom CSS.

Comment: @Tarekis do you use Bootstrap? this works in case if you use Bootstrap

Comment: It does not seem to, either you have a modified version or any other than 3.3.5, see [here](http://www.bootply.com/bP1zMco8Y3).

Comment: sorry but not sure that Bootply works correctly for this case, because if you'll try to inspect the output you'll find that styles written above haven't been applied.

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you are talking about, bootply never had an issue for me. See this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/fvyKvnn), CSS code correctly handled by Bootply.

Comment: Nevertheless, you are using unneccesary custom CSS, and did not see how OP broke his own code, misusing `input`-`label` standard use and continued with broken code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form role="form">
    <h4><font face="B Nazanin">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      گزینه اول
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">        
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      گزینه دوم
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">
    </label>
   </font></h4>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Answer not working, it breaks the code, and there is no explanation.