# mdl checkbox should be on right for RTL languages

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using mdl-checkbox and a text on the right side of the checkbox.
I would like to switch the order of these two components in case of RTL languages (text to the left of the checkbox) but I can't move the text to the left (it is always on the right).

I tried many variations of "dir=rtl", direction:rtl, align, etc.. but the text remain on the right side.
I also tried using some CSS options but I still failed to switch the order.

```
<label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
    <input id="MdlCheckBox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-checkbox__input" />
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">My Text</span>
</label>
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/80mfmnw4/5/)

How can I easily switch the order between the text and the checkbox without affecting the rest of the page?

All other components on the page behave fine in RTL languages.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741513/set-right-to-left-radio-button-in-bootstrap

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work on mdl-checkbox. Standard checkbox switch fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the links given below. These might help you creating check boxes.

[Github Link](https://github.com/WebRTL/material-design-lite-rtl): I have not used but you can check it. May this one also helps you.

[RTL CDN for MDL](http://rtlcss.com/cdn/css-frameworks/material-design-lite/) : I have created snippet using this.

[Check this one also](http://mdl.rtlcss.com/)

```css
#a {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/mdl/1.2.1/material.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/mdl/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">
  <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">Checkbox</span>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks that `<link href="https://cdn.rtlcss.com/mdl/1.2.1/material.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` solve the checkbox direction problem but it corrupts many other components position and colors.

Comment: Then you have to apply your own css by overwriting mdl css. Using `float` or removing/changing `position` attribute. Check by inspecting and change css using DOM inspector

Answer (score 0):

After making diff with material.rtl.min.css with material.min.css I found that the following CSS solve the problem:

```
.mdl-radio.is-upgraded, .mdl-checkbox.is-upgraded{padding-right:24px}
.mdl-radio__outer-circle, .mdl-checkbox__box-outline{right:0;}
.mdl-radio__inner-circle {right:4px;}
.mdl-radio__ripple-container, .mdl-checkbox__ripple-container{right:-10px;}
```

[JSFIDDLE Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/80mfmnw4/8/)

Thank you all for your help!