# How to change HTML page layout including all content to be from right to left

Tags: html, css, survey

I am using an online survey tool (alchemer.com) previously known as surveygizmo.com. I need to create an Arabic survey, which means that the alignment must be from right to left. The tools support some configurations which aloowed me to align the text from right to left. However, the problem is that their settings did not change the alignment of the radio buttons (the answer choices) to be from right to left. I contacted the support, which pointed to me that there is CCS and HTML customisation. I find  this HTML code. Can you help me make the HTML page to be aligned from right to left (including the radio buttons and not text only). See the code and the image that illustrate the problem.

```html
<div class="sg-wrapper">
        <div class="sg-header">
            <div class="sg-header-hook-1"></div>
            <img class="sg-header-image" src="[template("header image url")]" alt="[template("header image text")]"/>
    
            [template("survey title")]
            
    
            <div class="sg-header-hook-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sg-content">
            <div class="sg-content-hook-1"></div>
    
            [template("error message")]
            [template("page title")]
            [template("page description")]
            [template("page contents")]
    
            <div class="sg-content-hook-2"></div>
            
            <div class="sg-footer">        
                <div class="sg-footer-hook-1"></div>
                
                [template("button bar")]
                [template("progress bar")]
                [template("footer text")]
        
                <div class="sg-footer-hook-2"></div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

The problem is shown here where the radio buttons should appear in the right before the text starts. I could not align them. Is there anyway to do this from the HTML or CCS?
[image]

Comment: there are a lot of ways to align stuff the way you want. please show us what have you tried

Comment: Change your `<body>` tag to `<body dir="rtl">`, reload the page and check what remaining elements need extra 'right-to-left' handling in CSS... In CSS you could use `body { direction: rtl }`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741513/set-right-to-left-radio-button-in-bootstrap ???